# get scale of mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page with the meta viewport set like this:

```
<meta id="testViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
```

My page(s) are laid out like this (this is simplified)

```
<div data-role="page" id="article1">
    <div data-role="content">
    //page 1 stuff
    </div>
</div>

      <div data-role='page' id='article2'>
    <div data-role='content'>
    //page 2 stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

I've managed to navigate between the two pages, and enable pinch zoom scaling for only the second page using this script:

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function (event) { //swipe to plot
    if (event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {
        var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if (nextpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false
            }, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    var mvp = document.getElementById('testViewport');
    mvp.setAttribute('content', "width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=4");
    return false;
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function (event) { //swipe to input
    if (event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true
            }, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    var mvp = document.getElementById('testViewport');
    mvp.setAttribute('content', "width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1");
    return false;
});
```

Everything is working well, but I'd like to disable the 'swipe navigation' (excuse me if that terminology isn't correct) if the scale of the second page ("artice2") is greater than 1, but I can't figure out how to get the value of the page's scale.  In case you can't tell, I'm very new to this... so examples are much appreciated.

Comment: Andbody? Bueller Bueller?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is save height and width of screen once the page is shown `pagecontainershow`. And then, on *swipe* get the current height and width. If the current height/width is greater than inital height/width, ignore the *swipe*.

```
/* vars */
var windowWidth, windowHeight, currentW, currentH;

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (e, data) {
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
}).on("swipeleft", "[data-role=page]", function (e) {
    currentW = window.innerWidth;
    currentH = window.innerHeight;
    if (currentW == windowWidth && currentH == windowHeight && $(this).next("[data-role=page]").length != 0) {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", $(this).next("[data-role=page]"), {
            transition: "flip"
        });
    }
}).on("swiperight", "[data-role=page]", function (e) {
    currentW = window.innerWidth;
    currentH = window.innerHeight;
    if (currentW == windowWidth && currentH == windowHeight && $(this).prev("[data-role=page]").length != 0) {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", $(this).prev("[data-role=page]"), {
            transition: "flip",
            reverse: true
        });
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/teqahu/2/edit?html,output)**